# How to decipher this VimGolf answer?

Tags: vim

[the VimGolf challenge](http://vimgolf.com/challenges/4d1a34ccfa85f32065000004)

From:

```
Make the pairs of lines match up by making each second line same as first:

# Appending text:
The name "Vim" is an acronym for "Vi IMproved"
The name "Vim" is an acronym for

# Editing text:
Vim is a text editor originally released by Bram Moolenaar in 1991 for the Amiga
Trivia: Vim is a text editor released by Bram Moolenaar in 1991 for the Amiga

# Deleting text:
Vim has a vi compatibility mode
Vim has a vi compatibility mode but when not in this mode Vim has many enhancements over vi
```

To:

```
Make the pairs of lines match up by making each second line same as first:

# Appending text:
The name "Vim" is an acronym for "Vi IMproved"
The name "Vim" is an acronym for "Vi IMproved"

# Editing text:
Vim is a text editor originally released by Bram Moolenaar in 1991 for the Amiga
Vim is a text editor originally released by Bram Moolenaar in 1991 for the Amiga

# Deleting text:
Vim has a vi compatibility mode
Vim has a vi compatibility mode
```

One of the top answers that requires the fewest keystrokes is:

`:g/v/t.|+d<CR>ZZ`

I'm trying to understand why this work. What's the meaning of `v`, `.`, `|` in this context? Moreover, where can I find the relevant sections in `:help`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
:g/v/command
```

executes `command` on every line matching `v`.

```
:t.
```

copies the current line below itself.

After that, the original "second line" is deleted.

In short, the author of that solution is thinking out of the box: instead of manipulating the second line, he simply duplicates the first line and deletes the second.

As for the documentation:

```
:help :g
:help :t
```